# sort array of numbers and nulls in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, null

I need some help to write sorting function for DataTables. I have a column that contains currency - numbers with positive and negative values as well as blanks. 
I would like to have the nulls appear as last (/first) but they always come before the negative values. Could anybody hint me towards the solution?

Comment: Show us some code of your tries so far, then we can help.

Comment: have you tried anything.please add it to question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hint is to change the nulls to Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY or Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY when you are sorting

Answer (score 1):

Given an array of numbers which also contains `null`, if you want to sort them and keep `null` at the end of the results, you can customize your sort function this way:

```
var num = [-22,55,30,0,0,null,350,null,10000,-20];

num.sort(function(a,b){
    if (b == null) return -1;
    else if (a==null) return 1;
    else return a > b
});

// [-22, -20, 0, 0, 30, 55, 350, 10000, null, null]
```

This example above treats null as the largest number so when sort the array, nulls come last (see the sort function). If you want the reverse order, you can make a modification to that customized sort function.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - `return a > b` will return `true` or `false` which is a `1` if `a` is greater than `b`, or `0` if `b` is greater than `a`, however in a `sort()` function `0` means that the values are equal.